# how can I import python module tkinter in gitpod

Tags: cicd, python

I can't import pyton module `tkinter` in my gitpod workspace.

My .gitpod.Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM gitpod/workspace-full-vnc
USER root
RUN apt update && apt install -y python-tk python3-tk tk-dev
```

but when I run my project I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basic-screen-changer.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

`python --version` shows me `Python 3.8.6`.
Installed packaged are:

```
itpod /workspace/pydiag $ dpkg -l |grep ^ii |tr -s ' ' |cut -d ' ' -f2,3 |egrep '^python.*tk|^tk'
python-tk 2.7.18-1
python3-tk:amd64 3.8.5-1~20.04.1
tk 8.6.9+1
tk-dev:amd64 8.6.9+1
tk8.6 8.6.10-1
tk8.6-blt2.5 2.5.3+dfsg-4
tk8.6-dev:amd64 8.6.10-1
```

Answer (score 1):

That problem occurs because the `workspace-full-vnc` image uses `pyenv` and the module path is different ([source](https://github.com/gitpod-io/workspace-images/blob/73eeb0eeba2142d04a345e9de7aff4249d7384b5/full/Dockerfile#L201)). To use python modules, you need to install them using `python2` or `python3 -m pip install ...`.

Comment: This doesn't work. 
As pointed at [community.gitpod.io](https://community.gitpod.io/t/how-to-install-tk-and-tkinter-gitpod/274/2?u=makayabou), tkinter **has to** be installed _before_ pyenv, so it needs to be done while building workspace image.